# What's the reason for the change from "-аго" to "-oго"?

Tags: правописание, дореформенная-орфография

> Таяніе снѣга въ сѣверной части Ладожск**аго** бассейна...

This sentence is taken from a book published in 1908.  I understand that the spelling reform of 1917 simplified things by reducing the number of letters and signs used to write the language, but what's the idea behind replacing *аго* by *oго* to mark the ending for the genitive singular in masculine and neutral adjectives?

After all, the vowel is reduced to /ə/ in spoken Russian irrespective of its being spelt *а* or *o* and the sequence of sounds gives /əvə/ whether you write *аго* or *oго*.

Comment: The goal of the 1918 reform was the simplification of the orthography. So, the idea behind this particular change was to remove the need to learn and remember when one should write *-аго* and when *-ого*. *-аго* was used only for the adjectives ending (in nominative) in -ый, -ій, other adjectives required *-ого*.

Comment: @tum_ actually one of the goals was exactly simplification of the orthography.

Comment: And what of forms like больнóго? Did it used to be больнáго??

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The 1918 orthography reform was not something that came into existence all of a sudden after the Bolsheviks came into power. In fact, this question was quite a hot topic from the early 20th century. Russian academics had quite heated discussions on what had to be changed in Russian spelling. The 1918 reform was based precisely on the results of such disputes.

In particular, in 1912, Russian linguists had a meeting where they — among other things — proposed this exact change. The decisions made at that meeting were published in the booklet ["Постановления Орфографической подкомиссии"](https://www.prlib.ru/item/359219). Luckily, they also made a point of elaborating on why those decisions were made.

Here's the part (transposed to the modern orthography by me) that clearly explains their motives:

> В склонении имён прилагательных, местоимений прилагательных и причастий мужского и среднего рода родительный падеж единственного числа в современном правописании имеет два окончания *-ого* и *-аго* (*-яго*). Причём первое окончание употребляется при ударении на первом *о* (*слепого*, *второго*, *какого*), второе при отсутствии ударения на предпоследней гласной (*добраго*, *перваго*, *котораго*, *синяго*, *волчьяго*), хотя ещё не так давно в прилагательных именах писали *-аго* также и при ударении на звуке *о* в предпоследнем слоге (*слепаго*). Написания *-аго*, *-яго* появились у нас под влиянием церковно-славянской письменности.
>
> Имея ввиду: 1) показания современных окающих говоров, сохраняющих *-о*, а не *-а*, например в *доброго*, *первого*, и 2) то обстоятельство, что различение в письме ударной и неударяемой гласной в родительном падеже не находят соответствия в написании других падежей тех же слов (*слепому* и *доброму*, *о слепом* и *о добром*) — подкомиссия предложила в твёрдом склонении писать -*ого*, ..., в мягком -*его*.

In short, they decided to do it, as they explain, because:

- Up until that point, the -o spelling was not non-existent.
- In other cases, it was already spelled with an -o, so they decided to make the spelling consistent.

I'll add to this the following motives (some of which one can deduce from the document itself):

- Historically, Russian linguists tend to prefer etymological spelling to the phonological one in many cases. For instance, in Belarusian, it's quite the opposite; that's why we have "грамота" in Russian and "грамата" in Belarusian.
- Even if we consider phonetic consistency, a spelling such as "усопшаго" wouldn't make much sense.

I'm also attaching a scan with the actual quote for anyone who's interested.

[image: Scan of booklet explaining the orthography change (transposition is above)]

As a side note: One of the most active opponents of this reform, philosopher Ilyin, [used](http://speakrus.ru/articles/il-pr1.htm) the following counter-argument against the new spelling (adopted up to that point):

> Мы различаемъ «самъ» (собственнолично) и «самый» (точно указанный, тождественный). Родительный падежъ отъ «самъ» — «самого», винительный падежъ — «самого». А отъ «самый» — «самаго». «Я видѣлъ его самого, но показалось мнѣ, что я вижу не того же самаго»... (письмо изъ современной Югославiи). Въ кривописанiи это драгоцѣнное различiе гибнетъ...

While this distinction was indeed lost, luckily nothing dramatic happened ;)

Comment: "While this distinction was indeed lost luckily nothing dramatic happened ;)" - especially given the distinction can be indicated by stress.

Comment: @CocoPop The expression is "came *to* power". "Came *into* power" is passive, and completely inappropriate for this event.

Comment: @ElementsinSpace There's nothing passive about that phrase in that context: https://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/come+into+power

Comment: @ElementsinSpace From the Chicago Tribune, first sentence: https://www.chicagotribune.com/news/ct-xpm-1989-07-23-8902190922-story.html

Comment: @CocoPop 
Even the Chicago Tribune prefers ["came to power" (2520 results)](https://www.google.com/search?q=site%3Achicagotribune.com+"came+to+power") to ["came into power" (103 results)](https://www.google.com/search?q=site%3Achicagotribune.com+"came+into+power").

Comment: @ElementsinSpace And *I* happen to like the sound of *into* in this context. My problem isn't with either one of those prepositions — I personally would've said they *seized* power. What I don't like is your assertion about *into* being passive and especially "inappropriate," neither of which it is.

Comment: @CocoPop  I'd like to apologise somewhat.  Upon reflection, [no matter how old fashioned](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=came+to+power%2Ccame+into+power&year_start=1800&year_end=2019&corpus=en-2019&smoothing=3) the expression "came into power" is, it's not necessarily passive, and is perfectly valid phrasing.  I think it just sounds wrong to my ear because it reminds me of the expression "came into an inheritance".

Comment: @ElementsInSpace No harm done! I could tell right away that that was your confusion, but didn't want to promote an argument. When you've been an editor for as long as I have, you learn to stand by your decisions when they're correct and not выёжиываться  At the end of the day, we're all here to learn!

Comment: @ElementsInSpace Also, I'd like to point out that the phrase *come into power* isn't rendered old-fashioned by that Ngram. The thing is that *came to power* there doesn't necessarily only refer to our phrase; in includes instances like "Bowen was much more frank when it **came to power** stations" and "When it **came to Power** Rangers, Higgins wrote the big epic lore-busting series while Ryan Parrott handled the character-driven series." all of which I was able to find in books. Unfortunately, you can't isolate this phrase in the context we're discussing. But it's very much still valid today.

Comment: @CocoPop I got a similar result with ["Bolsheviks came to power" vs "Bolsheviks came into power"](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=Bolsheviks+came+to+power%2CBolsheviks+came+into+power&year_start=1800&year_end=2019&corpus=en-2019&smoothing=3).

Comment: @ElementsInSpace That's interesting. I guess *to* is indeed more popular in this context. Perhaps *into* is more prevalent in speech, and perhaps the speech of Americans. No idea.

Comment: @ElementsInSpace By the way, are you a native English speaker? I always assumed you were Russian.

Comment: @CocoPop I'm Australian. English is the *only* language I know (aside from a few handfuls of words from several European languages).  For a challenge, I learn to touch type in Russian (йцукен layout) earlier this year.  Since then, I've only watched half a dozen or so video lectures on Russian for absolute beginners.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/149645/discussion-between-cocopop-and-elements-in-space).